# How to load fancybox when the visitor comes from a referer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, rules, referer

Update: Now it popups from a specific referer =)

Here is my fancybox code:

```
 if (document.referrer) { //if for the referrer
    referrerone = /referrersite.com/;
    if (referrerone.test(document.referrer)) {


    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({ 

    }); 



$(".various").fancybox({ 
hideOnContentClick: true,
showCloseButton: false,
transitionOut : 'none',
transitionIn : 'none',


}).trigger('click'); 

$('.fancybox-media').fancybox({ 
openEffect  : 'none', 
closeEffect : 'none', 

helpers : { 
media : {} 
}
}); 


}); 
}
}
```

I want to add some static rules like the Popup plug-in for wordpress allows:

-Fancybox will auto close after some seconds.

-Not from an internal link: Shows the PopUp if the user did not arrive on this page via another page on your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
document.referrer
```

to get the last page which your page has been loaded from